# How do I write a File in python, with a variable as a path?

Tags: python, file, tkinter, savefiledialog, filedialog

I am trying to open a file, which I save before, in the program. Then I want to write some text, into the file. But it gives me the following Error, I have already looked for solutions in google and also here on stackoverflow, but the solutions didn't work.

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/kevin/Music/playlist.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"
```

and my Code:

```
def create_playlist():
playlist_songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir=r'C:\Users\kevin\Music')
str(playlist_songs)
playlist_file = str(filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w",defaultextension=".txt"))
with open (playlist_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(playlist_songs)
```

I hope you can help me. I thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: `playlist_file` contains the string `"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/kevin/Music/playlist.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"`, not just `"C:/Users/kevin/Music/playlist.txt"`, causing the issue.

Comment: Ok, and how can I change this, or better said, why is this text additional text in there ?

Comment: I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `playlist_file` variable contains the string `"<_io.TextIOWrapper name='C:/Users/kevin/Music/playlist.txt' mode='w' encoding='cp1252'>"`; not just `"C:/Users/kevin/Music/playlist.txt"`, causing the issue.

Simply add:

```
playlist_file = playlist_file[25: playlist_file.index("' ")]
```

so that your code becomes

```
def create_playlist():
    playlist_songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir=r'C:\Users\kevin\Music')
    playlist_file = str(filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w",defaultextension=".txt"))
    playlist_file = playlist_file[25: playlist_file.index("' ")]
    with open (playlist_file, 'w') as f:
        f.write(playlist_songs)
```

Runnable example:

```
from tkinter import filedialog

playlist_songs = filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir=r'C:\Users\kevin\Music')
playlist_file = str(filedialog.asksaveasfile(mode="w",defaultextension=".txt"))
playlist_file = playlist_file[25: playlist_file.index("' ")]
with open (playlist_file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(playlist_songs)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it worked. Now the data should be stored in a file. That file should be read later from the program, through user input, but the file doesn't have to be a file, which could be read by a human (encryption or binary or something like that is not needed, but in which file format should I store the data ? Txt, Csv, Json ? What is the best ?

Comment: @baumanager Is the data one filename? If so, I would recommend a txt file.

Comment: @baumanager If multiple filenames, a csv file. If a dictionary, a json file.

Comment: The data is just paths of songs. It gets saved in the second line: at asksavefile, there I have to determine the extension. So I have to choose a filetype there. Which filetype should I choose there ? This saved file then gets read from: with open.

Comment: Ok thank you, so I think a csv file would be the best.